# javascript sort list of lists by sublist second entry

Tags: javascript, sorting

How can I sort a list of lists by order of the last element?

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
var mylist = [ [1, 'c'], [3, 'a'],  [5, 'b']];
mylist.sort(function(a,b){return a[1]-b[1];});
```

My call to `sort` has not effect, and `mylist` remains in the same order.

Comment: use > or < instead of -

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```js
var mylist = [ [1, 'c'], [3, 'a'],  [5, 'b']];
mylist.sort(function(a,b){return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);});
console.log(mylist)
```

Use `a[1].localeCompare(b[1])` to sort the list in the ascending order or `b[1].localeCompare(a[1])` for other way round. This way you will be comparing two strings. You were trying to subtract one string from the other which return `NaN`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var mylist = [ [1, 'c'], [3, 'a'],  [5, 'b']];

// to sort by 1st NUMBER element; minus also used for object such as date 
mylist.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] - b[0];}); 

// to sort by 2nd STRING element with >. 
// strings can be compared based on alphabetical order with > or <, 
// but not with a math order operator -, which is supposed to used for comparison between number or date.
mylist.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] > b[1];});
```

Above mentioned examples gives sorting in ascending order, here I note what I understand for who may need:
to sort in ascending order [1,9,7] to [9,7,1], we could image there is an empty array[], then we'll just put each element one by one to this array in the right order (based on comparison with existing elements).

```
function(a,b) { return b - a; }
```

here a is existing one, b is the one we are going to put in the array.

- if return > 0 (true)   >> [b,a] , we could consider the return value as the order of a, positive/true means a should put later, that's the sort() means.
- if return <=0 (false)  >> [a,b]

for [1,9,7], the loop will be:

```
[]

// to put 1
[1]

// to put 9
a = 1, b = 9, b - a > 0 ==> [9,1]

// to put 7
a = 9, b = 7, b - a < 0 ==> [9,7,1]

a = 1, b = 7, b - a > 0 ==> [9,7,1]
```