# Sorting a list of lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of lists in ascending order based on the second element in javascript. I'm following this answer [javascript sort list of lists by sublist second entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599303/javascript-sort-list-of-lists-by-sublist-second-entry/41675199) but my list remains the same.

```
var a = [ [[1,2,3],10], [[5,6,7],0] ]
a.sort(function(x,y){return x[1] > y[1];});
```

Comment: Can you tell what is your expected result?

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer is wrong (how did it get 10 upvotes anyway?). You need `-` here: `x[1] - y[1]`

Comment: that answer was for strings

Comment: @AvcS it should not work for strings either.

Comment: @AcvS I tried with string but it did not work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing them with `>`, you should subtract one from the other using `-` to sort in ascending order:

```
var a = [ [[1,2,3],10], [[5,6,7],0] ]
a.sort(function(x,y){return x[1] - y[1];});
```

Comment: This way works, but I do not know what is the difference with my original implementation. The comparer which we pass on sort function should return a boolean, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TungTran: nope, it should return -1, 0, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [ [[1,2,3],10], [[5,6,7],0] ]
a.sort(function(x,y){return x[1] - y[1];});
```

Use `-` instead of `>`.